# Shader that prioritizes lowest alpha value

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, glsl, transparency, shader

I'm creating a 2D fog of war effect, where I'm cutting through a dark overlay using a depth mask. This is the effect…

[image]

It works well, and adding a transparent texture on top of the depth mask creates a more natural 'fog bordering' effect…

[image]

Here's the current shader code doing that:

```
Shader "Mobile/Unlit/Transparent Blend" {

Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color (A=Opacity)", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Base (A=Opacity)", 2D) = ""
}

Category {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True"}
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

    SubShader {Pass {
        GLSLPROGRAM
        varying mediump vec2 uv;

        #ifdef VERTEX
        uniform mediump vec4 _MainTex_ST;
        void main() {
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; 
            uv = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;    
        }
        #endif

        #ifdef FRAGMENT
        uniform lowp sampler2D _MainTex;
        uniform lowp vec4 _Color;
        void main() {   
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(_MainTex, uv) * _Color;    
        }
        #endif      
        ENDGLSL 
    }}

    SubShader {Pass {
        SetTexture[_MainTex] {Combine texture * constant ConstantColor[_Color]}
    }}
}
```

}

However there's a problem when I try to combine multiple fog holes together to create a route. The depth masking works great, but the transparent 'fog border' textures on top overlap each other…

[image]

I think what I need to do is somehow get the shader to put the pixel with the lowest alpha value into the depth buffer and ignore anything else. E.g.:

```
if ( newPixel.alpha < currentPixelInDepthBuffer.alpha )
currentPixelInDepthBuffer = newPixel;
```

But I don't know where to start with this. I'm still learning all the ins and outs of shader programming so I'm unsure if this would be a blending type, a blend operation, needs depth testing, or if it's even possible at all. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you just discard fragments with highest alpha values?

Comment: I can certainly try that approach. I know how to check the alpha value of the texture the shader is attached to, but I don't know how to access the pixel info from any possible textures that might be underneath it. How can I compare the information?

Comment: glEnable( GL_ALPHA_TEST ); This will be tested outside your shader. I think it is tested after your shader is processed but I'm not entirely sure, you'll have to test it.

Comment: You could also write to a texture instead of the back buffer, and use that texture as a sampler to query the alpha value but I really think this is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again Jean-Simon. I was writing to a texture before but you're right on the overkill and it was a bit slow. I think what I could do is add the line `AlphaTest Less DstAlpha` but I believe DstAlpha is a property unique to `Blend` and I don't know how to read this info from the frame buffer outside of the `DstAlpha` command.

Comment: I don't really understand what the "DstAlpha command" is.

Comment: DstAlpha is just a blending property in ShaderLab that is a shortcut for 'Destination Alpha Pixel'. It's the equivalent of the current fragment's frame buffer source alpha value. How can I get that manually?